# DllNotFoundException on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load shared libraries in Unity. It works on Windows/Editor but not on Android, whatever I do or use for libraries I always get the DllNotFoundException.

I am using lib.so files, those are for 32BIT ARM EABIS, so the cross platform compilation seems to succeed.

my lib.so files are in the `Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabis-v7a/` folder.

I tried different syntax for DllImport (assuming the lib is called Plugin, and the files Plugin.dll and libPlugin.so) :

```
[DllImport("Plugin")] => works for Windows only
[DllImport("libPlugin.so")] => obviously wont work for Windows, but doesn't work for Android either.
```

If I open the .apk with winrar, libs are in the `libs/armeabis-v7a` folder.

The smartphone I use for my tests is an OnPlus3 with a armv8 processor.

Anyone managed to sucessfuly load a shared native library on Android ? Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

EDIT:

plugin code can be found here : https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

C# code can be found here : https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/7e001dde3acaad70ed188b75e686f23574f81388/FFmpeg.AutoGen/FFmpegInvoke.cs

Adding FFmpegInvoke.cs in the Unity Project or generating the FFmpeg.Autogen.dll and adding it to the project gives the same result (dll just makes the Unity Project faster to build).

Answer (score 2):

I noticed few things you are doing wrong:

> my lib.so files are in the Asset/Plugins/libs/armeabis-v7a/ folder.

That should be at:

`Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a`

If you have the x86 architecture version of the plugin,you should place them at:

```
Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/x86
```

> I tried different syntax for DllImport (assuming the lib is called
>   Plugin, and the files Plugin.dll and libPlugin.so) :

None of those are correct. If the plugin file name is *"libPlugin.so"*, you should use *"Plugin"* as the name.

- Do not include the lib prefix.
- Do not include the ".so" postfix.

Again, if the plugin name is *"libVideoPlayer.so"*, you have to use *"VideoPlayer"*. The "lib" and ".so" are removed. Nothing else will work.

One final note for you, for Android C++ plugin, you do not need to export the plugin. For example, `DLLExport __declspec(dllexport)` is not necessary.

Although, you must put the function name inside "`extern "C"`"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the first problem, I made a typo error, my folder is actually Assets not Asset.

Comment: Ok. Then fix the second problem I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: my libs are called libVideoPlayer.so and VideoPlayer.dll. I use Dllimport("VideoPlayer"), which result in a DllNotFoundException. 
libs are the ffmpeg ones, so I assume they are coded correctly for shared libraries.

Comment: Your question does not show that you are doing it correctly. You mean you followed what's in my answer and you are still getting that error on Android?

Comment: This is how I did until now :
[Dllimport("VideoPlayer")]
public static extern void some_function();

(the Dllimport("libVideoPlayer.so") was just a test I made once, forget about it)

It works for Windows but not for Android, the libVideoPlayer.so is in the .apk so Unity adds it correctly to the packet.

Comment: How about this? I want you to create a simple plugin for android. Edit your question and post **C#**, the **C++.h** and **C++.cpp** file. Follow what I posted in the answer. I want to see the whole simple plugin. You are totally doing something wrong that I can't tell without your code. It should have only one function that returns an integer just for simplicity.

Comment: By the way, your first comment is still wrong. Read my answer properly. It should be `Assets/Plugins/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a` **not** `Asset/Plugins/libs/armeabis-v7a/`. Notice the "Android" in the file name.... If that's a typo too then go ahead and do what said in my last comment.

Comment: typo again sorry about that. I edited my post, thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello, I managed to build a simple shared library with a simple function returning an integer, and it worked on Android. But I still dont manage to get ffmpeg libraries to work on android, getting the DllNotFoundException everytime. I tried so many parameters with the ffmpeg ./configure file

Comment: I can't believe you linked a full FFmpeg lib here with hundreds/thousands of lines of code. My intention was to help you get started and I just did. You have to do the porting yourself. I don't think anyone will do all that for you since that takes time. It takes lot's of time. You can Google how to create new C++ class instance from C#.

Comment: It seems like when I Dllimport a ffmpeg lib that needs an other ffmpeg lib (for example libavcodec need libavutil) the first lib fails to load the second one, resulting in a DllNotFoundException. There is no c++ involved here, only native C libraries and C#/Unity3d.

Comment: Having the same problem. I firstly used ffmpeg and opencv in `arm64` and everything works fine. Then I switched to v7a and constantly having this DllNotFoundException. Any luck?

Comment: @Programmer any luck?