# DllNotFoundException for Unity3d Android c++

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine

I'm building a very simple c++ Shared Library in Android Studio, and using CMAKE to build .so for x86, x86_64, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a

The resulting files are called `libnative-lib.so`

I'm using Unity3D (2018.3.11f1). and the .so files are copied to Plugins/Android_x86, Plugins/Android_x86_64, Plugins/Android_armeabi-v7a, Plugins/Android_arm64-v8a.

Each of the plugins shows with correct settings in the inspector preview

My C++

```cpp
extern "C" int initTest() {
    return -1;
}
```

my c# (calling the plugin 'native-lib' which is consistent with [advice at the Unity3D manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html) and elsewhere)

```cs
    [DllImport("native-lib", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int initTest();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(initTest());
    }
```

It always results in DllNotFoundException error

> DllNotFoundException: native-lib

Comment: No, the advice in the Unity3d manual (and elsewhere) suggests "Note that pluginName should not include the prefix (‘lib’) or the extension (‘.so’) of the filename." Edited the Q to reflect this.

Comment: I have of course tried it that way, it didn't work, but let's be clear the manual says "should not include the prefix (‘lib’)"

Comment: @remy_rm see also answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027714/dllnotfoundexception-on-android/44028008#44028008 & here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509848/android-studio-c-ndk-library-example

Comment: Have you tried removing the "lib" prefix from your file name then? The filename and dll import names must match, so if having a "lib" prefix in the import is the issue remove it from the filename. For example call it "testDLL.so" and DllImport "testDLL"

Comment: are you sure that your so is getting deployed?  (just asking the obvious question because ... you've not ruled it out explicitly)

Comment: @remy_rm the name of the file is required to have the prefix for android to recognise it as a shared library afaik - thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: @UKMonkeyI'm not sure exactly what you mean, is the the file being created and put in the correct directory? If so, then yes.